# AWS Read-Replica Increased three times then it's master

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

RDS-MySQL with master and read-replica. Read-Replica created as per AWS guidelines for example replica should be same size of master.

but now read-replica gave error of low storage, so I have added some storage 2 times.

Now the situation is

Master Allocated Size 500 Gb  Used Space 400Gb
Read-Replica Allocated Size 2000 GB Used Space 1600 GB

So my question is if master is less then how could read-replica increased to 3 to 4 times.

please suggest

Comment: What is the value of `innodb_file_per_table` in the parameter group?

Comment: innodb_file_per_table = 1

Comment: but point is  all parameters in Master and replica are same so please suggest accordingly . now I have to reboot my replica or add some extra storage and RAM

Comment: I understand that the parameters may be the same, but the value might be important, even if they are the same.  The most likely explanation of this issue (or, at least, the only one coming to mind) is that you are running queries on the replica that are large and complex or not optimally indexed, so they require very large temporary tables and possibly you may be sitting on those connections, preventing their release.  Create a new replica, and observe it, it should match the master until you start querying it, and if it begins to grow after that, you have an explanation.